# What's the best way to evaluate test error during training?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a neural network I'm training with TensorFlow. Actually, at each iteration, I can compute the training cost to pass to the optimizer. A pseudo code of my implementation is:

```
def defineNetworkStructure(): # layers 
    ...

def feedForward():
    ...

def defineCost():
    ...

def defineOptimizer():
    opt = ...

def train(train_X, train_Z, ...):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for i in range(N):
            _, ith_cost = sess.run([opt, cost], feed_dict={X:train_X, Y:train_Y})

            print("Cost at {} is {}".format(i, ith_cost))
```

Now, inside the loop, I'd like to insert something like:

```
ith_cost = sess.run([opt, cost], feed_dict={X:test_X, Y:test_Y})
```

**Note:** test_X and test_Y instead of train_X and train_Y.

However, if I do so, I'll modify the value of the tensorflow variable `cost` and consequentely (but I'm not sure), I'll influence the optimization process.

What is the best way to achieve this task in tensorflow?

Comment: As long as you don't run any optimization operation (e.g. `opt`) and your `cost` operation doesn't contain any neither, there should be no problem inserting your validation line.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you've missed here is, you shouldn't run `opt` on test_X and test_Y.

Just doing `sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X:test_X, Y:test_Y})` will output your testing-loss and in no-way affects the training or optimization process.

Comment: That opt was a typo. I copied/pasted the line above and I forgot to delete opt. I'll give a try to your suggestion